# Android - Catching onPause without being the active Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Is there any way to catch onPause() in a java class that is Not an activity? I have native code with a Java-helper class that is used in other apps, and whenever those apps enters background I want to prepare for it too. How can I solve this? Is it enough to have my Java class extend some class to get the onPause(), even though its not registered as an activity in manifest etc?

Answer (score 0):

Create a public method named `onPause()` or `prepare()` or `whateverSuitYou()` in your helper class, and invoke it from the `onPause()` of your `Activity`.

Comment: So I have to extend my helper-class as an Activity, will I get the callback then? Even though it is not in the android-manifest?

Comment: You are creating an object of your helper class in the Activity, right?

Comment: No I am not. My helper class contains static methods I am calling from native code, thats it

Comment: And you want to do something inside the helper class when your activity is paused?

Comment: when my activity is about to be pauses yes, such as the onPause callback

Comment: So create the `prepare` method in your helper class, then inside your Activity override the onPause() and call your prepare method.

Answer (score 0):

Today we can use registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks() of the Application class and provide onActivityPaused().

Example:

```
AppContext.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
  @Override  
  public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {
    //handle here
  }
}
```